# “Undefined control sequence” error with fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, latex3

As a result of updating the l3kernel, l3packages, and l3experimental, a XeTeX document I'm working on no longer compiles. I've narrowed down the problem to fontspec failing to find a control sequence that was seemingly earlier available. The minimum working example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tinos}
\begin{document}
This is a minimal working example.
\end{document}
```

It fails to compile with the log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=xelatex)
\write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 16 languages loaded.
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3unicode-data.def)
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def))
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty)
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd))
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd))
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def))))
(/home/pan/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \str_case:nnn 

l.3 \setmainfont{Tinos}

?
```

Comment: We've recently removed some deprecated functions and Will obviously left one in `fontspec`. I'll prod him to fix it: for the moment, `\usepackage{expl3}\ExplSyntaxOn\cs_set_eq:NN \str_case:nnn  \str_case:nnFcs_set_eq:NN \str_case_x:nnn  \str_case_x:nnF\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: Kurt, Tinos is a freely available font downloadable from Google fonts.

Comment: Joseph, thanks. I think I have some time to spare, so I will wait until Will fixes fontspec. Given his track record, I think he will do it very soon!

Comment: There is a typo in Joseph's comment; the correct code has a backslash instead of the capital F. `\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN
\str_case:nnn
\str_case:nn
\cs_set_eq:NN
\str_case_x:nnn
\str_case_x:nnF
\ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by a passing issue in a package.