# Undefined control sequence with mhchem

Tags: mhchem

Using `pdflatex [Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)]` to compile the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

throws the following error:

> ```
> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
> !
> ! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-not-defined"
> ! 
> ! Control sequence \str_case:nnn undefined.
> ! 
> ! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
> ! 
> ! For immediate help type H <return>.
> !...............................................  
>
> l.58 \cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnn { Vnn }
> ```

Note that I am using `mhchem` v4.01.

Any help in regards to fixing this issue is appreciated.

Comment: You need to update your TeX distribution – specifically files of the l3kernel.

Comment: According to MikTeX' package manager, I am already running the latest version of l3kernel (SVN 5666).

Comment: That should certainly be recent enough, but nevertheless, that function *does* exist. How strange. Have you tried just *that* code in a minimal document? `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{expl3}\ExplSyntaxOn\cs_generate_variant:Nn\str_case:nnn{Vnn}\begin{document}hi\end{document}`?

Comment: Running your code returns two separate errors:
`kernel/command-not-defined`; `Control sequence \s undefined.` and
`kernel/missing-colon`; `Function '\s' contains no ':'.`.

Comment: Welcome! Can you add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and post the output?

Comment: I have the same error message with fontawesome and fontspec.

Comment: @Bernard With a different engine, you mean?

Comment: @cfr I hope that this is what you're after: http://pastebin.com/aCWuCW8Z

Comment: Hmm. That was it, yes. MiKTeX appears to have newer versions of the l3 stuff than TeX Live (I just updated to be sure I'd got the current stuff). @Bernard Do you have those `566*` versions from this week? TL is still giving me `5630`. Did they introduce a bug, do you think?

Comment: @SeanAllred I don't think so. *Downgrading* might work, though...?

Comment: `graphics.cfg` is the only thing which looks *older* than TL gives me. The rest is the same or newer, and I bet the newer is the problem here.

Comment: It seems to be [this problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255743/undefined-control-sequence-error-with-fontspec) as mentioned perhaps by @Bernard. [This comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255743/undefined-control-sequence-error-with-fontspec#comment612140_255743) includes a workaround.

Comment: It seems that `fontspec` and `mhchem` rely on a function which is considered deprecated and has now disappeared....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Joseph Wright wrote a message to 10 package authors last weekend (and I am sure he does not mind quoting it here).

> Hello all,
>
> I've done a recent expl3 update in which I've remove functions
>   deprecated in 2013, following the pattern we've set up. A sweep of TeX
>   Live shows there are a few stray uses of \int_case:nnn, \tl_case:Nnn,
>   \str_case:nnn and \str_case_x:nnn, all of which should now end "F"
>   (e.g. \str_case:nnF). These are easy to miss (I've got one myself to
>   fix in siunitx), but updates of your code to match expl3 would be
>   welcome.
>
> Where I can I've made pull requests on GitHub/BitBucket with fixes.
>   I've also asked that TL don't update the expl3 version until people
>   have a chance to address this.
>
> Regards,
>
> Joseph

So, MikTeX updated too quickly. Less than a week seems not enough for 10 package authors to update their packages.

**Update:** I updated mhchem. The upload to CTAN was made 2015-07-23. It will take a day to get approved, a day to distribute to the mirrors and a few extra days until you will eventually see it as a MiKTeX update.

This **addendum** might be useful for others, but is not related to the mhchem package: After correcting the signature (from `:nnn` to `:nnF`), the functions were renamed once again to correct the type of expansion they perform. `\str_case_x:nn(TF)` is now `\str_case_e:nn(TF)` (the `x` expansion is slightly different from the `e` expansion, and the latter is correct for these functions).

Comment: After the new update to 4.04, I get this new error @mhchem:

- LaTeX error: "kernel/command-not-defined"
- Control sequence \prop_get:Nn undefined.

Comment: @TobiasDk You should have asked at a more obvious place. This error seems to come from chemgreek 1.0d. MikTeX seems to have not yet updated to 1.0e from February this year.