# XeLaTeX compilation fail (« Undefined control sequence. l.27 \sys_if_engine_luatex:T ») with fontspec package

Tags: xetex, fontspec

After an update of all my packages, the upgrading from my old MiKTeX 2.9 to the last version, and the refreshing of the file name database (FNDB), my `tex` file wouldn’t compile anymore. I identified the problem as coming from the `fontspec` package which worked perfectly fine right before updating everything.
When running, the compilation stops first on the following lines:

```
Package: fontspec 2019/03/15 v2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
! Undefined control sequence.
l.27 \sys_if_engine_luatex:T
```

If I force to run though, I get several other errors which appear in the log file below. No PDF file emerges from the process.

I tried to uninstall (and deleting all files left) then to reinstall my MiKTeX distribution several times with 64 bits and 32 bits versions in case I did it wrong but it did not change anything to my problem.

I also checked with other packages as the one linked to the `LaTeX2ε` and `LaTeX3` as it seemed to be in [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295697/fontspec-package-causes-error) but installing, uninstalling and reinstalling the packages `l3kernel` and `l3packages` had no effect on the compilation. This [temporary solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255743/undefined-control-sequence-error-with-fontspec) from 2013 had no effect neither.

Ater several tests, I also found out that other packages seemed to be affected by my issue: `polyglossia` (as it works partly upon the `fontspec` package), the `manyfoot` package and the `perpage` package. For the manyfoot and perpage packages, I am not sure if it is related to the fontspec package althought it also worked fine before any update. It seems to me that the core issue stands with the `fontspec` package.

Any idea of how I could fix that issue?

I am using `MiKTeX 2.9.7050` (32bits) and `Texmaker 5.0.3` on `Windows 10`. Here is a **M(N)WE**:

> ```
> \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
> \usepackage{fontspec}
> \begin{document}
> Hello world!
> \end{document}
> ```

And here is the `log` file until the first error (I may not post the whole log file which looks like a spam to the forum):

> ```
> \c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count110
> L3 Module: l3box 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental boxes
> \c_empty_box=\box27
> \l_tmpa_box=\box28
> \l_tmpb_box=\box29
> \g_tmpa_box=\box30
> \g_tmpb_box=\box31
> L3 Module: l3coffins 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Coffin code layer
> \l__coffin_internal_box=\box32
> \l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen109
> \l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen110
> \l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen111
> \l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen112
> \l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen113
> \l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen114
> \l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen115
> \c_empty_coffin=\box33
> \l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box34
> \l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box35
> \l_tmpa_coffin=\box36
> \l_tmpb_coffin=\box37
> \l__coffin_display_coffin=\box38
> \l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box39
> \l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box40
> \l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen116
> \l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen117
> \l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen118
> L3 Module: l3color 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental color support
> L3 Module: l3candidates 2014/11/23 v5466 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
> \l__box_top_dim=\dimen119
> \l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen120
> \l__box_left_dim=\dimen121
> \l__box_right_dim=\dimen122
> \l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen123
> \l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen124
> \l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen125
> \l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen126
> \l__box_internal_box=\box41
> \l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
> \l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
> \l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
> \l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
> \l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
> \l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
> \l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
> )
> (C:\Users\Erizo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\l3unicode-data.de
> f
> File: l3unicode-data.def 2014/11/23 v5465 L3 Unicode data
> )
> (C:\Users\Erizo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.def
> File: l3xdvidpfmx.def 2014/11/23 v5466 L3 Experimental driver: xdvipdfmx
> ))
> Package: xparse 2014/11/25 v5471 L3 Experimental document command parser
> \l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count111
> \l__xparse_m_args_int=\count112
> \l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count113
> \l__xparse_processor_int=\count114
> \l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count115
> )
> Package: fontspec 2019/03/15 v2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.27 \sys_if_engine_luatex:T
> ```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It looks like your version of `fontspec` is quite recent (2019/03/15), but your `l3kernel` is very old (2014/11/23). You need to update `l3kernel`.

Comment: Do you have an admin installation? Did you update as admin **and** as user?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I did try to update the `l3kernel`. I did uninstall then reinstall it from the MiKTeX console _as_  _an_  _admin_. The console indicates, indeed, that the package was "packaged on 12-12_2014". So I uninstalled them then used the `tds.zip` files from CTAN to install them semi-manually but it didn't change anything. Would the `tds.zip` be outdated? Do you think I should try to install the two packages by running latex on every `dtx` file? There are like 40 or 60 and the documentation is not really extensive on where to place them in my MiKTeX location tree.

Comment: @Mensch I do have an admin installation and I did update everything as an admin. It does not seem possible to update my packages as a common user after updating as an admin?

Comment: It is, first open MiKTeX Console, choose use as admin, update. Then change to your user account, open MiKTeX Console, choose use as user and update ... Do that always you have to update MiKTeX ...

Comment: @Mosley The `tds.zip` from CTAN should contain only the latest version. CTAN doesn't store package history. And you don't need to run `latex` through all the files, the main installation file is `l3.ins`, so if you run `pdftex l3.ins` it will already generate all the [necessary files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489648/134574). Although you shouldn't go this way: try to update through the MiKTeX console so that everything is in the right place. (I don't use MiKTeX, so I can't help you with that, sorry).

Comment: @Mensch I thought admin mode was enough but I will update `FNDB` and so on in both user and admin modes in the future, everytime I add packages.
@PhelypeOleinik Problem solved.
Thank you both for your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last it seems to me that you updated an very old version of MiKTeX which is already mentioned on the homepage of MiKTeX to can result in errors.

In your case it seems your MiKTeX system is corrupted and I would recommend to deinstall it completly (and TeXmaker too), then download the current complete installer from the homepage and install new. Why do you use a 32bit software (MiKTeX) on a 64bit system? Better use the 64bit version of MiKTeX: Go to https://miktex.org/download, click on `all downloads` and choose the `net installer 64bit`. After installing MiKTeX install the current TeXMaker too (then it should recognise the new MiKTeX and be able to call and use it).

With the following mwe (please see added command `\listfiles` to get a list of all used packages and version numbers in the log file)

```
% xelatex
\listfiles
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

I can compile with my current MIkTeX `XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.2.5)` without any errors or warnings an get the following list of used packages:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontspec.sty    2019/03/15 v2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2019-05-28 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2019-07-01 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2019-07-01 L3 programming layer 
l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def    2019-04-06 v L3 Experimental backend support: xdvipdfmx
fontspec-xetex.sty    2019/03/15 v2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
   tuenc.def    2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.cfg
 ***********
```

As you can see your used version for `expl3.sty` is simply too old.

I guess you did some changings on your MiKTEX system as admin, some as user and this causes your culprit.

Comment: I did a complete clean installation of `MiKTeX` (64bits) then a new installation of `Texmaker` (64bits) but I still had difficulties. Then I made a new clean installation of `Texmaker` _after_ _I_ _tracked_ _down_ _all_ _left_ _files_ related to the program. I assume you were totally right by talking about corrupted distribution as part of the problem. The problem was fully resolved when the new `Texmaker` made a real clean config when it couldn't find any old config file.

The `file list` is now up to date and the compilation runs smoothly.